# Can't find .sty files after changing shell

Tags: errors, texlive, paths

I installed my texlive in

~/Software/texlive/2020

and when I used bash, I had

~/Software/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux

in my PATH, which was all I needed to get all style files and packages.

Now I switched to zsh and added this directory again to my PATH but now compiler throws errors. I use vimtex for compilation, but I even tried using texstudio, and that also does not work.

What to do?

which tex even now gives
~/Software/texlive/20202/bin/x86_64-linux/tex

Comment: Where exactly did you add that to your path?

Comment: It was earlier in .bashrc. I forgot to move it in .zshrc right after shell change, and when I compiled a Latex file, the compiler started looking for packages in /usr/share/tex.. Moving PATH to .zshrc didn't help. I tried to change paths in texmf.conf but found it too complicated, so I gave up and now I am using repository version.

Comment: No idea about zsh but adding it only to bashrc or zshrc will only let you compile with it from the command line. If you also want to use it from an editor started via a menu you also need to at it to dot profile as editors never use bash or zsh

Comment: .profile? I think it was there too, but yes, I had pulled it out of .profile because I thought .profile was only for tmux like things. Thanks a lot for this info.

Comment: Dot profile is only read once, at login, thus what is executed there is a shared by all following processes including editors etc. Sadly we see in a lot of places that people are recommended to add the path change to bashrc or similar, but that is not enough. Remember if you change dot profile you'll need to lig out and in again for it to have an effect

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, that's what happened to me. Very helpful. That also explains why my rofi can't detect my mathematica.